# List of Hyperlinks, buttons, whatever that open to new browser window

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, hyperlink, listbox

I have a need to create a small window inside of a ASP.NET Web Page(aspx) which displays a list of usernames, when you click the username, I need a new broswer window (not tab) to open up to a specific size.  I can handle opening the new browser window assuming whatever control I use gets me into a code behind function where I can call....

```
 string url = "http://www.dotnetcurry.com";
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "OpenWin", "<script>openNewWin    ('" + url + "')</script>", false);
```

Here's the markup that's in the page for the link.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function openNewWin(url) {
            var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin', 'width=600,height=600,toolbar=1');
            x.focus();
        }
</script>
```

1.) What controls should I be using for this problem, what does the structure look like after I get the respective usernames back from the database?

Here's the closest I've come...This code uses an ASP.NET Bulleted List which I'm trying to bind to a list of HTML links which I would like to instead not POINT anywhere, but get me to the codebehind. Instead this Code actually renders on the page as the HTML (it isn't parsed into hyperlinks..)

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UsersBulletedList.DataSource = theContext.GetOnlineFavorites(4);
        UsersBulletedList.DataBind();
    }

  public IQueryable<String> GetOnlineFavorites(int theUserID)
    {
        List<String> theUserList = new List<String>();
        IQueryable<Favorite> theListOfFavorites= this.ObjectContext.Favorites.Where(f => f.SiteUserID == theUserID);
        foreach (Favorite theFavorite in theListOfFavorites)
        {
            string theUserName = this.ObjectContext.SiteUsers.Where(su => su.SiteUserID == theFavorite.FriendID && su.LoggedIn == true).FirstOrDefault().UserName;
            yourOnlineFavorites.Add("<a href='RealTimeConversation.aspx?UserName=" + theUserName + "'>" + theUserName + "</a>");
           //this needs to help me get into a codebehind method instead of linking to another page.
        }
        return yourOnlineFavorites.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Comment: Winforms, WPF, web?  Based on what you have described, it seems (to me at least) that a datagridview/gridview might be a good way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a `Repeater` on your page and bind your results from the `GetOnlineFavorites` method. Inside the `Repeater`, place a `LinkButton` with a `ItemCommand` event that adds your script to the page.

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repeater_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkButton"
            Text='<%# Eval("PropertyFromBindingCollection") %>'
            CommandName="OpenWindow" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AnotherProperty") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In here, the `Text` property of the `LinkButton` and the `CommandArgument` of the `Repeater` would be set to some properties from your collection.

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        repeater.DataSource = theContext.GetOnlineFavorites(4);
        repeater.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void repeater_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "OpenWindow")
    {
        string arg = e.CommandArgument; // this could be the url, or a userID to get favorites, or...?
        //Your open window script
    }
}
```

Now, when the user clicks one of the LinkButtons, it will fire the `ItemCommand` event for the `Repeater`, check the `CommandName` (set on the LinkButton), and then get the `CommandArgument` set on the `LinkButton`. If you set the `CommandArgument` as a URL, you can use that in your OpenWin script, otherwise use whatever data you set as the argument to get the URL you want to open.

Comment: this is awesome! Everything is working flawlessly, but for some reason, the open window script isn't opening the window (I can step through and see it execute the code, but nothing happens) if you can help me find out why, the green check mark is yours! :)

Comment: I can see that the script you add is missing the `type="text/javascript"` attribute. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with your issue though. If you open the F12 dev tools in your browser, is the script added on the page somewhere?

Comment: yes it is. Also adding a regular button with a "Click" event that goes to the function works fine, but for some reason not this way.

Comment: I was doing it in a user control and referencing this as opposed to this.Page in the Script Register. D'oh.